# Conjecture about the value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\cos(x)}\sin(\sin(x))}{x}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am conjecturing that the integral in question is equal to pi. Here is my work. Can anyone tell me if it is right?

$$I:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\cos(x)}\sin(\sin(x))}{x}\,dx$$

$$I=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\cos(x)}\sin(\sin(x))}{x}\,dx$$

$$I=2\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{e^{ix}}}{x}\,dx$$

$$I=2\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ixn}}{n!}\,dx$$

$$I=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ixn}}{x}\,dx$$

$$I=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\,dx$$

Let $$nx\longrightarrow{x}$$

$$I=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$$

$$I=\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\cos(x)}\sin(\sin(x))}{x}\,dx=\pi$$

Comment: But $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} = e$

Comment: I'm not sure about the Let $nx -> x$ step. But the rest (aside from above comment) looks good

Comment: @Alborz it's just a substitution, i.e. let $y=nx$

Comment: [Numeric evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B2%2FPi*Exp%5BCos%5Bx%5D%5DSin%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5D%2Fx%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C200Pi%7D%5D) seems to give $\pi(e-1)$.

Comment: $2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\,dx = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\,dx$, then you can do the substitution $nx \mapsto x$, which is essentially $x = u/n$, to avoid $n=0$.

Comment: The only thing I would add to make this proper is to assert $e^{\cos x}\sin(\sin x) = \operatorname{Im}\{e^{e^{ix}}-1\}$ rather than just the iterated exponential. It's still true as the imaginary value is unaffected, but it renders the integrals in between convergent rather than divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Putting together the hints found in the comments. Start with eyeballfrog's numeric evaluation:
$$I = \pi(e-1)$$

As NoName points out, the $e$ comes in because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{n!} = e$, not $1$ as you apparently mistook it. But why the $-1$?

Note that when $n=0$, $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin nx}x\,dx = \int_0^\infty 0\,dx = 0$, so this term makes no contribution to the sum.

But your next step of making the substitution $u=nx$ leading to $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin u}u\,du$ is only true when $n\ne 0$. By overlooking this restriction, you turned the $0$ integral into a non-zero integral.

So in addition to making the changes Ninad Munshi points out that will fix your divergent integrals in the middle (alternately, leave the $\Im$ operator inside the integral, so there is no real part to diverge), you need to drop the $n=0$ term from the sum before you make the substitution. And doing so results in exactly $$I = \pi(e-1)$$ as expected.